# ADAL to MSAL v2 Migration on Angular 9

Tags: angular, adal, msal

Is there a way to migrate from ADAL to MSAL v2 in an Angular 9 application programmatically from the terminal without having to modify all the code?
I would like to perform the migration in a way that I don't have to modify all the adal dependencies and the existing code.

Comment: I very doubt. I was reviewing migration of Adal to MSAL in C# and in complex code with perfect error handling, you need to spend a time on it. Those interfaces are not 1:1.